# what is wrong with this code of listbox in msaccess vba

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have wrote this code to populate the listbox through VBA Code but its not working. i cant understand what's wrong with it.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Dim strsql As String
strsql = "select hotel_id, hotel_name from Hotels"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strsql)
Me.List0.RowSource = hotels                            'where hotels is name of table
Me.List0.ColumnWidths = "1 in; 2 in"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Me.List0.RowSource = hotels
```

to

```
Me.List0.RowSource = strsql
```

You're trying to set your list rowsource to a table, which Access doesn't understand.  it wants a SQL string, and "strsql" is that string.

You could also just set it directly like:

```
Me.List0.RowSource = "select hotel_id, hotel_name from Hotels"
```

Comment: by doing this i get only hotel_id in list box. the hotel_name is not visible there.                                                        i have defined rowsource as Me.List0.ColumnWidths = "1 in; 2 in"

Comment: Usually you define that stuff in the actual control, not in code.  Make sure your columncount is set to 2 as well, it defaults to 1.